# Is there a way to get a MessageBox to automatically dismiss after a set interval of time?

Tags: vbscript

I have a VBScript to alert on an event with a MessageBox, but I would like this to be automatically dismissed after 5 seconds or so. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Google: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2005/03/14/how-can-i-automatically-dismiss-a-message-box-after-a-specified-length-of-time.aspx

Answer (score 10):

Use the WshShell Object's Popup method.  It has a timeout parameter.

```
intTimeout = 10      'Number of seconds to wait
strMessage = "This is my message box!"
strTitle = "Hello, world!"

Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
intResult = WshShell.Popup(strMessage, intTimeout, strTitle)
```

<del>For more, check out my article [Mastering the MessageBox](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/Mastering-the-Message-Box/) on ASP Free.</del> ([archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20161003120820/http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/VB.NET/Mastering-the-Message-Box/))