# VBSCRIPT MsgBox VbYesNo countdown

Tags: vbscript

Tried searching for the answer, all were too simple, or didn't match what I need. I have a message box, and I have it displaying information correctly. I have a Yes and No button. I want a timer, so when the timer runs out, it continues. If someone hits yes, it continues down the code, if they hit no, then it returns the user elsewhere. This is what I have, please help.

```
akey = MsgBox ("Image OS = " & ImageType & vbcrlf & _
  "ComputerName = " & ComputerName & vbcrlf & _
  "TimeZone = " & TZone & vbcrlf & _
  "Ghost Server = " & Server & vbcrlf & _
  "Broadcast Method = " & BMethod & vbcrlf & _
  "Ghost Session = " & GhostSession _
  , vbyesno + vbquestion,VN & " Please Confirm")
```

Comment: A MessageBox is a special purpose (very simple) popup window. If you need something fancier, then you need to create a Dialog, which goes outside the bounds of vbscript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a MessageBox to automatically dismiss after a set interval of time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252237/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-messagebox-to-automatically-dismiss-after-a-set-interval)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use Popup instead of Msgbox...

http://ss64.com/vb/popup.html

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

X = objShell.Popup("You have 3 Seconds to answer", 3, "Test", vbYesNo)

Select Case X
Case vbYes
    Msgbox "You pressed YES"
Case vbNo
    Msgbox "You pressed NO"
Case Else
    MsgBox "You pressed NOTHING"
End Select
```

Otherwise, you can try to manipulate an HTA or Internet Explorer window to do something similar.

Comment: Thank you. JUST what I needed. Modified to match my script.