# Timeout Msgbox popup

Tags: vbscript, autohotkey, msgbox

I have a small script that runs (basically fires a msgbox to tell people that their account passwords are about to expire).

I want it to close itself after say 30 minutes, but cannot get the syntax right to do it, can anyone help?

Below is the section that calls the msgbox

```
if (daysLeft < warningDays) and (daysLeft > -1) then

Msgbox "Your Password Expires in " & daysLeft & " day(s)" & " at " & whenPasswordExpires & chr(13) & chr(13) & "Please ensure that you change your password before" & chr(13) & "its expiry time to prevent any disruption of service.", 4144, "PASSWORD EXPIRATION WARNING!"

End if
```

--

Gavin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get a MessageBox to automatically dismiss after a set interval of time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10252237/is-there-a-way-to-get-a-messagebox-to-automatically-dismiss-after-a-set-interval)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `Popup()` method of the `WShell` object can timeout after a specified number of seconds. Here's an example that should disappear after 30 minutes.

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "Hello!", 1800, "Title"
```

Comment: Works really good,just remember that the time set as 1800 is in seconds.

Comment: Is there a way to make this popup SystemModal or a way to keep it on top of other windows?

Comment: Add `,4096` to the end of the command to open as a system modal message box that appears in a top most window.

Comment: Note that the timeout works in vbscript but not in Office VBA.  If you want to use it in Office VBA, try this method that uses mshta.exe:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44837192/1898524

Comment: I'm not the only one having issues with in Office VBA. Discussion and an alternative using mshta.exe are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31143673/1898524).  Note that the mshta method does not support carriage returns and always shows the message on the primary monitor.  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57512186/1898524) shows a API MsgBox that supports timeout, carriage returns, and return values.  @Bond, your answer here was an inspiration for me.  I've been using VBA 20 years and never knew a timeout was possible until this week.

Answer (score 1):

You wont be able to do it that way, you will need to use your own custom form and timer, because a message box can only close on user interaction.

Comment: This article suggests its possible though:http://autohotkey.free.fr/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm

Comment: Gavin if you care to look towards the bottom of that article the mention of IfMsgBox and example syntax makes it clear that the documentation is not for a dialect of VBA, VB6, VB.NET or C#

Answer (score 0):

echoing the point made by @user3585329, to do this you may want to create a HTA application, which can display the information in a internet explorer form.

Comment: This article suggests it is possible: http://autohotkey.free.fr/docs/commands/MsgBox.htm

Comment: I don't know what that relates to, but i have not seen a timeout facility on the msgbox before see [link](http://ss64.com/vb/msgbox.html) or MSDN microsoft official webpage [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sfw6660x(v=vs.84).aspx)

Comment: the link you have sent is from AutoHotKey which is a custom scripting language and so is not vbscript, but very similar syntax to it. As mentioned i think you will need a HTA application to create what you need

Answer (score 0):

FIX that like this:

```
CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Popup "MessageHere", 10, "Title"
```

TimeOut is in SECONDS, not in miliseconds!