# Outlook - Pass variable to be displayed in temporary Popup

Tags: vba, shell, outlook

In Outlook I have setup the following code to temporarily display a message.

However I cannot work out how to pass a variable (`aMessageLabel`) containing the text to be displayed.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim aShell

    Set aShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    aMessageLabel = Chr(34) & "No Emails to be Forwarded!" & Chr(34)

    aShell.Run "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.shell"").Popup(aMessageLabel,5,""Message""))"

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please describe a bit more exact what you want? What is not working?

Comment: (1) Where do you want to pass the message from?  Who or what knows that No emails are to be forwarded?  (2) Why aren't you using VBA's MsgBox to display the message?  You may have a good reason but it is not obvious from your question.

Comment: 2. I will be setting up the macro to run every ten minutes and want a pop up to tell the user that the macro is running if they happen to be working in outlook at the time.

Comment: 1. If I was using a normal message box then Msgbox aMessageLabel would give me a pop up reading "No Emails to be Forwarded", however when I run the above code the pop up is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works

```
Sub Test()

    ' this is the resulting windows command (you can run at command prompt)
    ' mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject("WScript.shell").Popup("No Emails to be Forwarded!",5,"Message"))
    ' the "5" is number of seconds that the popup message will live

    Dim aShell
    Set aShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    aMessageLabel = "No Emails to be Forwarded!"

    Dim cmd As String

    ' multiline
    cmd = "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.shell"").Popup("""
    cmd = cmd & aMessageLabel
    cmd = cmd & """,5,""Message""))"
    Debug.Print cmd
    aShell.Run cmd

    ' one line
    aShell.Run "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.shell"").Popup(""" & aMessageLabel & """,5,""Message""))"

End Sub
```

Comment: I have update my macro and the popup are appearing and disappearing with the relevant text, thanks for your help!