# timer is not working for message box in vb script

Tags: vbscript, catia

I'm trying to write simple script, a timer for a message box

But this is not working when I run it.
What do I have to do to get this timer for message box working?

```
Sub Test1()

    Dim objSHL
    Set objSHL = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    objSHL = objSHL.Popup("This will last for ", 3, "title", vbYesNo)

End Sub
```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44837192/17172829) you can a find an solution to get the display timer also work in catscript-