# How to insert a break line in 'mshta.exe' pop up (VBA macro)?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a msgbox that does not stop the macro. Is there a way to insert a break line, same as 'vbNewLine' for msgbox?

None of these works:

```
Chr(13) 
Chr(10)
vbLf 
vbCr 
vbCrLf 
vbNewLine
"<br>"
```

```
Function mshta(ByVal MessageText As String, Optional ByVal Title As String, Optional ByVal PauseTimeSeconds As Integer)
'mshta.exe as an alternative for msgbox

'[...] some other stuff

Dim ConfigString As String
Set WScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

ConfigString = "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"")." & "Popup(""" & MessageText & """," & PauseTimeSeconds & ",""" & Title & """))"
WScriptShell.Run ConfigString

End Function
```

If I cal the function:

```
mshta "Hello<magic?>World"
```

I want it to display:

```
Hello
World
```

Comment: Can anyone help? :(

Comment: See - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61750883/insert-a-new-line-in-a-pop-up-message-box-created-by-createobjectwscript-shell/61758234#61758234

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution that supports carriage returns that use an API call instead of WScript.Shell and works in Excel VBA. It supports standard enumerated parameters like `vbQuestion + vbYesNo` and can return the user response.  `32000` is returned if the timeout occurs.

This also has the advantage of showing the popup on the same monitor as the app instead of the main display.

```vb
' This part needs to be at the top of a VBA module
#If Win64 Then 
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function MsgBoxTimeout _
        Lib "user32" _
        Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
            ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, _
            ByVal lpText As String, _
            ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
            ByVal wlange As Long, _
            ByVal dwTimeout As Long) _
    As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function MsgBoxTimeout _
        Lib "user32" _
        Alias "MessageBoxTimeoutA" ( _
            ByVal hwnd As Long, _
            ByVal lpText As String, _
            ByVal lpCaption As String, _
            ByVal wType As VbMsgBoxStyle, _
            ByVal wlange As Long, _
            ByVal dwTimeout As Long) _
    As Long
#End If


Sub TestMsgbox()
    Dim ReturnValue

    ReturnValue = MsgBoxTimeout(0, "Do you like this message?" & vbCrLf & "This message box will be closed after 4 seconds." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "(See Immediate window for return value)", "Return Choice", vbQuestion + vbYesNoCancel, 0, 4000)
    Select Case ReturnValue
        Case vbYes
            Debug.Print "You picked Yes."
        Case vbNo
            Debug.Print "You picked No."
        Case vbCancel
            Debug.Print "You picked Cancel."
        Case 32000
            Debug.Print "Timeout before user made selection."
    End Select
End Sub
```

More info:
https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3836-excel-message-box-timer-timeout.html

Comment: Hi Ben, this is quite an interesting one, I've not heard of it before! Unfortunately it doesn't do what I want it to do. I need the code to keep running while the message is displayed on the screen. I upvoted your answer but not marked as correct one. Thank you for your effort!

Comment: I did quite a bit of searching and could not find a way for mshta to support a carriage return.  For Excel, you may need to create a UserForm with a timer event to display a message and allow code to keep running.

Comment: Thank you Ben, ahh that's a shame I was hoping there is an alternative maybe. I don't fancy the userform idea at all to be honest!