# Insert a new line in a pop up message box created by CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Tags: excel, vba, vbscript, windows-scripting

Sorry but I was trying to find the answer for hours but could not figure it out.
I tried playing with vbNewLine and vbCrLf but could not make it to work in the function and in the function call.

How do I add a new line with the code below?

Tried this but it did not work:

```
checker = MessageTimeOut("Underlying raw data in the workbook has been updated." & vbNewLine & "This will close automatically.", "UPDATE RAW DATA - COMPLETED", 5)
```

Also tried:

```
checker = MessageTimeOut("Underlying raw data in the workbook has been updated." & vbCrLf & "This will close automatically.", "UPDATE RAW DATA - COMPLETED", 5)
```

I want the "This will close automatically." shown in a new line.

```
Function MessageTimeOut(str_message As String, str_title As String, int_seconds As Integer) As Boolean
    Dim Shell
    Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Shell.Run "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.shell"").Popup(""" & str_message & """," & int_seconds & ",""" & str_title & """))"
    MessageTimeOut = True
End Function


Sub Some_Sub()
    ' some lengthy code....
    Dim checker As Boolean
    checker = MessageTimeOut("Underlying raw data in the workbook has been updated. This will close automatically.", "UPDATE RAW DATA - COMPLETED", 5)
```

Comment: I tested with removing the message variable and like so: `Popup(""" & "Test Line 1" & vbCrLf & "Test Line 2" & """," & int_seconds & ",""" & str_title & """))"` with no success - I also tested passing a variable from your sub to the function `Dim myMessage As String` `MessageTimeOut(myMessage,...)` and could see the function receives the formatting but the popup won't recognise it. I also tried hardcoding into the message other new line things I found on google like `n with no luck - this looks to perhaps be more of a powershell/VBS issue than to do with your VBA...

Comment: It might be worth changing your tags to better suit the issue.

Comment: Also [this SO question is identifying and asking the same issue as yours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253640/how-to-insert-a-break-line-in-mshta-exe-pop-up-vba-macro) - might be worth looking into.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a break line in 'mshta.exe' pop up (VBA macro)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54253640/how-to-insert-a-break-line-in-mshta-exe-pop-up-vba-macro)

Comment: Thanks Samuel and Geart. The post you shared was not actually solved. I am looking into Tim's answer below.

Comment: With Tim's solution below, I think we can just play around with just vbLf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:  My previous answer wasn't using mshta which I think you needed in order to make your message asynchronous and allow your code to continue...

This does the trick:

```
Sub Test2()

    mshta "Me`s`s`age", "test", 5 '<<< all backticks become newlines

    Debug.Print "This runs right away"

End Sub


Function mshta(ByVal MessageText As String, Optional ByVal Title As String, _
            Optional ByVal PauseTimeSeconds As Integer)

    Dim ConfigString As String, WScriptShell
    Set WScriptShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    ConfigString = "mshta.exe vbscript:close(CreateObject(""WScript.Shell"").Popup(Replace(""" & MessageText & """,""`"",vbLf)," & PauseTimeSeconds & ",""" & Title & """))"
    WScriptShell.Run ConfigString

End Function
```

Comment: This solved my problem, Tim. Thank you for the "REPLACE" solution. I used ~ instead.